# Centering the placeholder for a Textfield MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to align a Placeholder to be centered within the Text-Field. Is there a way to do this? applying `text-align: center` to the input is not centering the placeholder.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed example code of what you're doing. Do you really mean "placeholder" or are you referring to the label (which is displayed very similar to a placeholder when the TextField is empty and doesn't have focus)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `&::placeholder` pseudoselector on `input` classname like below

```
 import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  input: {
    "&::placeholder": {
      color: "red",
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  }
}));

export default function Inputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      placeholder="Placeholder"
      InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.input } }}
    />
  );
}
```

A working [sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xc12m?file=/demo.js) link

Comment: I did not realize you were asking for `TextField` component, not the `Input` Component
FYI, TextField is using Input field underlaying and it is exposing `InputProps'  through we can pass `classes` props to underlying `Input` element.
You could have inferred this from the previous answer, I would recommend understanding more about Material-UI library and how we can override style and other stuff
`In-Short`: New Solution is working fine as well with TextField

Comment: do you by chance have a link to the overriding styles documentation regarding material ui @core.  Would be much appreciated!